# What application is responsible for reporting seen SmartTags to Samsung?

Tags: samsung

There must be some kind of technology on Samsung Galaxy phones that report SmartTags seen t Samsung. Is that technology in,

- The Samsung Android distribution
- The [SmartThings application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.oneconnect&hl=en_US&gl=US)
- Something else.

What actually is responsible for seeing and reporting these devices?

Comment: How do you know those tags are reported to Samsung? I did not find anything online that SmartTags system works like Apple's AirTag system (all Apple devices scan for AirTags and send info on found tags to Apple).

Comment: @Robert it's the same system. They're both Bluetooth LE tracking systems.

Comment: The used technology doesn't indicate if or if not found tags are reported to a central cloud service. But I finally found what you are talking about, it is called the "Galaxy Find Network". From what I read on https://www.samsung.com/ie/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-find-my-smarttag/ section "How can I join the Galaxy Find network?"  you have to agree to participate in this network. And it shows that scanning is not done by an app but a system service (as it is a system setting).