# How can I stop my phone from reporting my coordinates and detected devices to Samsung?

Tags: samsung

[Following on the footsteps of this question, *"What application is responsible for reporting seen SmartTags to Samsung?"*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245483/7425)

---

Given that *something* is doing this, is there a way with an authentic Samsung phone to opt out of this kind of spyware? Can I stop my phone from reporting SmartTags and other things (including my location) to Samsung?

To be clear, SmartTags work on Bluetooth LE. What sends the result of the Bluetooth LE scan and GPS coordinates to Samsung?

Comment: There is one and only one way to protect your privacy from Samsung, Google, Huawei, Xiaomi and so on..., and that is: stop using their hardware products. Or at least their software products, which on top includes their userspace environment on Android devices - commonly called ROM. Everything else you'll see on internet is either a partial solution or a complete lie. But even with a fully open-source custom ROM, your privacy isn't guaranteed. Their proprietary modem might be calling back home continuously even when you think your device is down.

Comment: @IrfanLatif while I appreciate the comment, and I sympathize with your stance (I run LOS as my daily driver), I have a reasonably well defined question that I'd like the answer to. I'm specifically asking about whatever reports SmartTags visible to Samsung.

Comment: My comment is a general answer to your question: *"How can I stop my phone from reporting my coordinates to Samsung?"*. Being concerned only about coordinates or SmartTags doesn't seem of much importance when they are collecting a lot of other information using a lot of other means. // Hopefully you'll get a precise answer to your question. Mine is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Samsung SmartTag web site](https://www.samsung.com/ie/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-find-my-smarttag/) you have to agree to make your device scan for tags (act as a "Find Node").

> #### How can I join the Galaxy Find network? If your SmartTag is out of the 120-metre range of the BLE (Bluetooth low energy) connection, it
>
> will require the help of the Galaxy Find network to be located.
>
> The Galaxy Find network is made from other Galaxy device users that
> have agreed for their devices to be used as Find Nodes. Find Nodes
> receive the signal from lost SmartTags and send the location
> anonymously to the SmartThings server, allowing for you to find your
> SmartTag no matter how far away it is.
>
> To help other SmartThings users by using your device as a Find Node,
> you will need to agree to offline finding in the SmartThings app. This
> is an option you can select when adding SmartThings Find.
>
> You can also agree to use your device as a Find Node through your
> settings. You'll be asked if you want to do this when setting up
> SmartThings Find.
>
> 1. Open the Settings app
> 2. Tap Biometrics and Security
> 3. Tap Find My Mobile
> 4. Tap Offline finding

So the answer should be not to enable this setting.